# Problem in installing WiFi External LAN from Installer CD to PC, O/S Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit

Tags: 12.04, wine

Unable to Install from the Installation CD, software of a WiFi LAN Card of MediaTek USB 2.0 -- 802.11N, by WINE application "Wine Windows Programe Loader or Q4 Wine". It shows an Error Message "RaRegistry.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to closed, We are sorry for the inconvenience,  This can be caused by a problem in the program or a deficiency in Wine, Error No. : 0x80040707,  Description : DLL function call crashed : InstAPI. EnumerateDevice         Setup will now terminate."  How it can be installed ?

Comment: This is the wrong way of installing a wifi driver. The right way would be to provide more relevant info, for example, the output of `lsusb`, assuming it is a USB adapter.

Comment: You're not supposed [to install drivers with Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Can_I_use_Wine_to_install_drivers_for_my_hardware.3F).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your Wifi is working OK.

Linux is supossed to have Wifi drivers by default. Some of them are restricted by licence and you have to install them manually - see  [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

If you still don't see wifi - try to use newest Ubuntu version - 15.10